# Get time ticks in DateTime format C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

Date time comes from Database side like this `"2021-03-08T21:27:21.065"` and then i have tried and format it from C# side like below,

```
string fullDate = Convert.ToDateTime(x.start_date).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

But i need to show last part of the date `065` as well.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=net-5.0#System_DateTime_ToString_System_String_ or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings have you read the documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff" is the format to include milliseconds. Please try this:

```
string fullDate = Convert.ToDateTime(x.start_date).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff");
```

Comment: Thanks. Best wishes.